# How can i replace all '\' and '/' characters, in a string to '-', in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following javascript.

```
window.location.href = _searchUrl + query.replace(/\s+/g, '+')
                                         .replace('/', '-')
                                         .replace('\\','-')
```

this replaces all spaces with `+` and only the first `\` and first `/` with a `-`.

i need to make it replace ALL `\` and `/` with a `-`

Any suggestions? or should this be URLEncoded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
query.replace(/\s+/g, '+').replace(/[/\\]/g, '-')
```

Comment: Initially i was hoping to use some EncodeURI stuff (as cletus posted) but because i'm trying to create a dynamic RESTful url, i think i need to stick with REGEX, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

The first regular expression replaces ALL the spaces because it has a 'g' modifier.

You need it for the other two 'replaces'

Answer (score 1):

You're basically doing a subset of the URI encoding. Use [`encodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/encodeURI) or [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/encodeURIComponent) as appropriate. See [Comparing escape(), encodeURI(), and encodeURIComponent()](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/) (escape() is deprecated).

Assuming `_searchUrl` is something like

```
http://mysite.com/search?q=
```

then you should do this:

```
window.location.href = _searchUrl + encodeURIComponent(query);
```

There is no need (or reason) to reinvent (partially) URI encoding rules with regular expressions.

Comment: Hmm. i thought this might be the case, which was why i suggested that in my opening post. The reason why i need this is becuase of dynamic RESTful urls. So i tried that and got this url => /search/23%2F24%2F5%2F6%2F2 foo ... which doesn't work :( Looks like i'll have to stick with REGEX then...